# No signature of method is applicable for argument types - expects another argument?

Tags: grails

I can't for the life of me find what is going on here. My code seems to be fine. Here is my call:

```
AccessToken accessToken = myService.getAccessToken(token, verifier)
```

Here is the method being called in myService:

```
public AccessToken getAccessToken(String token, String verifier){
   /* code stuff */
   return tokenResponse;
}
```

I get this error when I try to invoke myService.getAccessToken:

```
No signature of method: myService.getAccessToken() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Possible solutions: getAccessToken(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

Clearly getAccessToken is accepting two strings and I've confirmed that the values it's trying to pass are indeed strings. In the possible solutions it suggests I try passing a third argument. When I pass some third dummy argument, it works.

Why on earth is it thinking that this method needs another argument? This method doesn't implement the methods of an interface or abstract class. I know it's not much to go on, but if someone can just give me some possible causes I would much appreciate it. I feel like I'm going crazy looking at these few lines of code. I'm sure it's something silly that I'm looking right past.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and build? it could be that it is running an old version of your code.

Comment: It is possible that you are looking at source code of a version but using jar file of a different version. If the server is using different jar that could also cause the issue. May be you can recompile classes are restart all components.

Comment: or your `myService` is not really injected with the object you(r IDE) thinks it is.

Comment: Or you could be looking at the wrong file

Comment: Sorry everyone, major user error here. I thought I had cleaned properly, but apparently I had only cleaned my web server, not my API server. D'oh!!